# Invoking PowerShell cmdlets more quickly in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I am able to fetch user details from O365 using Powershell cmdlets in C#.
The problem is the fetching time. That is too slow.

It takes 2 seconds to each user so it will lead to a time problem if I have the bulk of users.

Here I am just want to print all the user's info like name, group details, licenses.
How can I do it more quickly?

Tried one:

```
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline UserDetailsPipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        UserDetailsPipe.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADUser");
        foreach (PSObject info in UserDetailsPipe.Invoke())  /////////*******
        {
            ArrayList Groups = new ArrayList();   // to hold memberOf
            ArrayList Licenses = new ArrayList(); // to hold of licenses

            string UserPrincipalName = info.Members["UserPrincipalName"].Value.ToString();
            string DisplayName = info.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString();

            //Getting MemberOf
            Pipeline memberPipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            memberPipe.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId '" + UserPrincipalName + "'| Get-AzureADUserMembership");

            //Getting Licenses
            Pipeline licensePipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            licensePipe.Commands.AddScript("$license = Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail -ObjectId '" + UserPrincipalName + "' | select ServicePlans ");
            licensePipe.Commands.AddScript("$license.ServicePlans");


                foreach (var licensenames in licensePipe.Invoke())////////*****
                {
                    Licenses.Add(licensenames.Members["ServicePlanName"].Value.ToString());
                }

            foreach (var memberOf in memberPipe.Invoke())////////*******
            {
                Groups.Add(memberOf.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString());
            }
       }
```

I know that I am invoking many pipelines. So how to get my answers by using only one invoke? (It may be in PowerShell class too).

Comment: Presumably O365 would have an API you could use instead?

Comment: I should work with PSCmdlets

Comment: If I use `PowerShell` class, That is also too slow than the above method

Comment: I had the same results as you, even when using something like Get-Process. It turns out that I had to go and remove any of the throw NotImplementedExceptions in my CustomPSHostRawUserInterface and my CustomPsHostUI.cs. I'm not sure what's going on in the internals here, but I think for every exception, System.Management.Automation must be doing a lot of extra processing.

When running your code, watch your debug output window, and see if there are a lot of exceptions. Then run another command such as Get-ChildItem which should have less exceptions. The execution time of GCI is much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the best solution will be to combine into as few scripts as possible to reduce the number of pipelines. I also would suggest using the `PowerShell` object instead of `Runspaces`

Also in order to get all results in the final `Collection` after invoking, use the `.AddStatement()` method. This is demonstrated below. [Documentation for AddStatement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addstatement?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)

This will need to be modified to your environment as I am simply getting the date twice to demonstrate returning both dates to the final collection.

```
using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()) {
    powershell.AddScript("Get-Date");
    powershell.AddStatement().AddScript("Get-Date");

    Collection<PSObject> result = powershell.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: If we add multiple scripts in the same line using a semicolon(;), will if affect the PowerShell memory?

Comment: @saravananks To my knowledge the more scripts you add the more memory PowerShell will consume but from the looks of your application it shouldn't be a problem. Are you having memory issues?

Comment: I will add more statements so that

Comment: @ivcbur actually how memory concepts works in powershell

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation about the memory concepts

Comment: @saravananks As far as I know, this is really just an interface to the 'command line' PowerShell so memory behavior would behave similar to how it would if you run these commands manually from the PowerShell prompt. There will be a slight additional overhead because of the C# object. If interested in more specific information it will be best to open another question directly about this.