# Powershell cmdlets invoking Only once - C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, office365

I need to invoke some PowerShell cmdlets only one time but I want to all the info from all the cmdlets using `C#`.

Eg:

```
Get-AzureADUser
Get-AzureADUserMembership
Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail
```

This all cmdlets have to be invoked only once. But I should get all the info.
How to do that using [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) class in C# so that time taken will be reduced?

Tried one by invoking multiple times:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
Pipeline UserDetailsPipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
UserDetailsPipe.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADUser");
foreach (PSObject info in UserDetailsPipe.Invoke())  /////////*******
{
    ArrayList Groups = new ArrayList();   // to hold memberOf
    ArrayList Licenses = new ArrayList(); // to hold of licenses

    string UserPrincipalName = info.Members["UserPrincipalName"].Value.ToString();
    string DisplayName = info.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString();

    //Getting MemberOf
    Pipeline memberPipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    memberPipe.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId '" + UserPrincipalName + "'| Get-AzureADUserMembership");

    //Getting Licenses
    Pipeline licensePipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    licensePipe.Commands.AddScript("$license = Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail -ObjectId '" + UserPrincipalName + "' | select ServicePlans ");
    licensePipe.Commands.AddScript("$license.ServicePlans");


        foreach (var licensenames in licensePipe.Invoke())////////*****
        {
            Licenses.Add(licensenames.Members["ServicePlanName"].Value.ToString());
        }

    foreach (var memberOf in memberPipe.Invoke())////////*******
    {
        Groups.Add(memberOf.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString());
    }
```

}

Comment: What is your actual problem? Are you saying they get invoked several times _by accident_ or are you simply looking for someone to do the work for you, giving you the code needed to solve the task? If you have code you're working with, edit your question to include it.

Comment: Is this the same question as the linked one?

Comment: @ivcubr yes, but there was no response

Comment: I tried a lot but nothing works fine

Comment: Why ask the same question again? That creates a duplicate. You have an open bounty on the other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoking PowerShell cmdlets more quickly in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206369/invoking-powershell-cmdlets-more-quickly-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Even though having the bounty, Nothing helped

Comment: @notjustme there was no answer in that question, so that may not be a duplicate

Comment: You literally opened it on Friday.

Comment: @ivcubr yes. But I tried but couldn't reduce the time taken for single invoke

Comment: @saravananks have you tried creating a .ps1 script and then using `Process.Start()`? Similar to a Windows batch file but with Powershell. You will have to do some extra reading back from the process stream but this may be quicker

Comment: @saravananks Are you asking how to use the `PowerShell` class? In the code you added it does not use this.

Comment: @ivcubr actually, Using `PowerShell` class it works fine. But the problem for each user it takes 1 to 2 seconds, I need to reduce the time only, So that If I invoked only once the time may be reduced

Comment: @saravananks Are you sure this isn't a response time from Azure? It may be that each command takes that long due to waiting for Azure. Is it quicker executing them manually from Powershell command line? (Just troubleshoot to see if it is a C# optimization or if that is just how long it takes Azure)

Comment: @ivcubr already checked with powershell command line that is faster than in c#

Comment: @saravananks Why not just create a single `pipeline` or `PowerShell` object and add all scripts to that and invoke at the end?

Comment: @ivcubr If it is, the last invoked lines output only gets stored in the collections, what about the initial cmdlets.

Comment: @ivcubr for eg: from the `Get-AzureADUser` I need objectID using that I need to invoke other cmdlets.

Comment: @saravananks I found a way to add multiple scripts and have all results in the resulting collection from the `Invoke()` method. If you need the object ID from before you will need to just use two pipelines

Comment: @ivcubr How will you seperate the results from the all results

Comment: @ivcubr I tried to add all scripts, but when I debug , the last line's output only resides the invoked line

Comment: @saravananks That is something you would have to handle based on the format of the returned results. Not sure what that looks like so can't really comment on how. If this is not an option I don't see a way to reduce the number of pipelines you need to use to increase the speed

Comment: @ivcubr tried again but last executed powershell script only gets stored as a result

Comment: @saravananks Ill add my solution as an answer to the original question. This one can be deleted since it is the same as the other

Answer (score 0):

Made all scripts together and invoked once as @ivcubr said and works somehow better than the previous method

```
public static void Display()
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        PowerShell UserDetailsPipe = PowerShell.Create();
        UserDetailsPipe.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADUser");

        Console.WriteLine("\n{0,-20}{1,-45}{2,-30}{3,-30}", "DisplayName", "UserPrincipalName", "MemberOf", "Licenses");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1,-45}{2,-30}{3,-30}", "-----------", "-----------------", "--------", "--------");


        var Users = UserDetailsPipe.Invoke();

        foreach (var info in Users)
        {
            ArrayList Groups = new ArrayList();   // to hold memberOf
            ArrayList Licenses = new ArrayList(); // to hold of licenses

            string UserPrincipalName = info.Members["UserPrincipalName"].Value.ToString();
            string DisplayName = info.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString();


            //Getting MemberOf
            PowerShell newPipe = PowerShell.Create();
            newPipe.Runspace = runspace;
            newPipe.AddScript("Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId '" + UserPrincipalName + "' ; $license = Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail -ObjectId '" + UserPrincipalName + "' | select ServicePlans ;$license.ServicePlans");
            var AllInfo= newPipe.Invoke();



            try
            {

                foreach (var licensenames in AllInfo)
                {
                    if (licensenames.Members["DisplayName"]!=null)
                        Groups.Add(licensenames.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString());
                    if (licensenames.Members["ServicePlanName"] != null)
                        Licenses.Add(licensenames.Members["ServicePlanName"].Value.ToString());
                }
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {

            }


            //Displaying UsersInfo
            for (int groupIndex = 0, licenseIndex = 0; groupIndex < Groups.Count || licenseIndex < Licenses.Count; groupIndex++, licenseIndex++)
            {
                if (groupIndex == 0 && licenseIndex == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,-20}{1,-45}", DisplayName, UserPrincipalName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,-20}{1,-45}", " ", " ");
                }
                if (groupIndex < Groups.Count)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,-30}", Groups[groupIndex]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,-30}", " ");
                }
                if (licenseIndex < Licenses.Count)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,-30}", Licenses[licenseIndex]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,-30}", " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```